# How to print all routes for a Yesod Application

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a compiling yesod application and would like it to print all the route information it has, including sub-sites.

What do I need to do to achieve this? Google has not given me any information on this.

I would like to do something similar to what Ruby on Rails has, with `rails routes`.

Comment: It seems, the function you need is `resourcesFromString :: String -> [ResourceTree String]` from `Yesod.Routes.Parse` module. But it isn't exported, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Will this also work for sub-sites? From what I gather in the documentation it is meant to parse the routes configuration string.